# Help me to find out the verse : "Brahma satyam jagat mithya, jivo brahmaiva naparah"

Tags: scripture, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

According to wikipedia, The [Famous verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivekachudamani#Famous_verses) from Vivek Chudamani (विवेकचूडामणि) is:

> **Brahma satyam jagat mithya, jivo brahmaiva naparah**
>
> Translation: Brahman is the only truth, the world is unreal, and there is ultimately no difference between Brahman and individual self

But I can't find that verse from vivek chudamani. I have a vivek chudamani of [Gitapress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gita_Press) Gorakhpur ([book code](http://gitapress.org/english/Search_main.asp):133). You can also find it from [sanskritdocuments](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_shankara/viveknew.html) : sanskrit [pdf](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_shankara/viveknew.pdf).

So, Where can I find the verse : **Brahma satyam jagat mithya, jivo brahmaiva naparah**?

Note: Verse no. 20 of vivek chudamani is not exactly this (though it contains first part of the quoted verse)

Also visit the [related](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10016/277) question.

Comment: I don't see anything exactly like that. Look at verses 464-470.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Have you any idea about the location of this verse (may outside of vivek chudamani)?

Comment: I have also heard/read that verse in many advaita mandirs like that of a datta mandir, they have a great dependency in advaita philosophy since it totally discards jagat(world) as mithya or maya. But I never had any encounter with that word in any text I know. +1 good question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Good question. Always quoted as Sankara, but no one gives the source text. It is from Sankara's *Brahmajnanavalimala* verse 20. It is available [here](http://www.celextel.org/adisankara/brahmajnanavalimala.html)

> 20. brahma satyam jaganmithyA jIvo brahmaiva nAparah
>   anena vedyam sacchAstram iti vedAntaDiNDimah

Yo can also check from [sanskritdocuments](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_shankara/):

**The 20<sup>th</sup> verse of [Brahmajnanavalimala](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_shankara/brahmajna.html?lang=sa):**

> ब्रह्म सत्यं जगन्मिथ्या जीवो ब्रह्मैव नापरः ।
>   अनेन वेद्यं सच्छास्त्रमिति वेदान्तडिण्डिमः ॥ २०॥

Comment: Yes, I've checked it from [sanskritdocuments](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_shankara/brahmajna.html?lang=sa)

Comment: By the way what about the half of verse posted in question: "slokärdhena pravakshyämi yad-uktam granthakotibhih"?

Comment: @pandya Haven't found the other half anywhere. Maybe you should ask the website that claims its from the vivekchudamani.

Comment: Well, I am accepting this answer because "Brahma Jnanavali Mala" by Adi Shankara covers the verse mentioned in the title of question. By the way, For "slokardhena..." I will make separate question/discussion. Thanks

Comment: So, is it the English Wikipedia that's in err. All other wikis translating from English version :)

Comment: @pinkpanther many errors on Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9970/3500), Adi Shankara's [Brahmajnanavalimala](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_shankara/brahmajna.html?lang=sa) has the complete verse.

Half verse "ब्रह्म सत्यं जगन्मिथ्या" is also present in [Niralamba Upanishad](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/niralamba.itx).

> तप इति च **ब्रह्म सत्यं जगन्मिथ्ये** त्यपरोक्ष ज्ञानाग्निना
>   ब्रह्माद्यैश्वर्याशासिद्धसङ्कल्प बीजसन्तापं तपः ।
>
> tapa iti ca **brahma satyaṃ jaganmithye**tyaparokṣa- jñānāgninā
>   brahmādyaiśvaryāśāsiddhasaṅkalpa- bījasantāpaṃ tapaḥ ।

Translation from [Nitaaiveda](https://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Upanishads/Sri_Niralamba_Upanisad.htm):

> Spiritual austerity is austerity where the fire of
>   transcendental knowledge, which teaches **"This material world is an
>   illusion"**, burns away the desire to have powers and opulences like
>   Brahma and others.

Comment: I am brahman the world is illusion (brahma satyaṃ jaganmithye)

Comment: Niralamba Upanishad (http://www.vedarahasya.net/muktika.htm) is one of the 108 Upanishads according to Muktika so it's an authentic scripture. Adi Shankara may have not quoted from numerous scriptures . That does not make them invalid @PrasannaR

Comment: who is the creator of vedarahasya.net/muktika page.. ask them.. why this is there i remeber @Rickross you already gave non existence version of rig veda quoting advaita statements in veda explicitly, its countered by james web of some professor saying that vedic statement is itself is bogus and newly added. Your credibility is question

Comment: Haven't understood what are you trying to say .. it's not important to find out who created that page .. you can find a PDF of Muktika Upanishad from any source you prefer and you will find Niralamba in it .. so whether you like it or not it's a valid scripture. it is not written in any scriptures that for any scripture to be valid Adi Shankara has to quote from it. Although undoubtedly he is greatest among all Acharyas but still no such rule is there @PrasannaR

Answer (score 0):

It is the 20th Shloka of the Vivekachoodamani. Kindly refer to the Vivekachoodamani commentary by Swami Chinmayananda published by the Chinmaya Mission. Also listen to lectures by Swamijis of the Chinmaya Mission - "Fundamentals of Vedanta through Vivekachoodaamani - Day 03 / 16" Talk by Swami Aparajitananda" on Youtube talks about this shloka in detail. Hari Om!

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Actually as I have mentioned in my question "Note: Verse no. 20 of vivek chudamani is not exactly this".

Comment: Compare the verse quoted in the question with 20th verse of Vivekachudamani