# Looking for the source scripture for the verse "Slokardhena pravakshyami"

Tags: scripture, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

My previous question was : [Help me to find out the verse : “Brahma satyam jagat mithya, jivo brahmaiva naparah”](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9960/277). In which I knew that in the **Brahmajnanavalimala** of Adi Shankaracharya, The verse is:

> ब्रह्म सत्यं जगन्मिथ्या जीवो ब्रह्मैव नापरः ।
>   अनेन वेद्यं सच्छास्त्रमिति वेदान्तडिण्डिमः ॥ २०॥

I've accepted it as it is the verse which I was looking for: "Brahma satyam jagat mithya, jivo brahmaiva naparah" is found from Adi Shankara's scripture - Brahmajnanavalimala.

But another confusing thing appeared is that many web sites say the verse:

> Slokardhena pravakshyami yad-uktam granthakotibhih
>   Brahma satyam jagat mithya, jivo brahmaiva naparah

Just [search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Slokardhena+pravakshyami) it on web and you will find lots of related articles about it. [Some](http://vedavedantamission.com/programs/advaita-vedanta/) of them also says it's from Vivek Chudamani. By the way, we've already [figured-out](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9960/277) that there is no verse like "Brahma satyam jagat mithya, jivo brahmaiva naparah" in Vivek Chudamani.

So, I want to know Where the verse (Slokardhena pravakshyami yad-uktam granthakotibhih...) is located in scriptures by Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: More said it is about 'Balabodhini', a text which is supposed to be written by Shankara. Since I have no access to this manuscript, I will search more for a photocopy of it and search inside (the manuscript is actually on Indian collections).

Comment: Following "Theosophy Or Psychological Religion" written by F. Max Müller, p.317 the reference book given in footnote is "Rational refutation of the Hindu philosophical systems" translated by FITZ-EDWARD HALL, Calcutta,1862. I have read this book and on page 127 "But entirely different from anything as yet encountered is the doctrine of the Vedantins touching the true state of existence, as they phrase it.

Comment: And this doctrine is summarized in this half couplet : "Brahma is true ; the world is false the soul is Brahma himself, and nothing other." Even if author is not given as we read "Who wrote this half -couplet is not known, though it is familiar to every Vedantin". Read that page and I think you should know that is maybe a later couple [or addition].  I think it is just a latter synthesis, without a known author.

Comment: You can not find that text anywhere in Shankara's works, that is the correct answer, because is a latter addition and not an original text of him..