# Does the individual soul actually feel pleasure or pain?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, atma

In Gita ch.13 v23 , the Lord says that the Supreme Purusha in this body is the upadrista (observer) , the anumanta (permitter) , bharta (supporter) and bhokta (the experiencer /  the one who experiences).

> upadrashtaanumantaa cha bhartaa bhoktaa maheshvaraha |
>
> paramaatmeti chaapyukto dehesmin purushaha paraha ||

Swami Chidbhananda, in his Gita commentary, explained the bhokta part by saying that the jivatman which is the reflection of the Supreme Lord, 'experiences' the insentient Prakriti. (In his Gita, it's ch.13 v22)

So does this mean the soul actually experiences, pleasure & pain?
Like when we feel sad, besides observing all the drama, does the soul also experience or feel sadness ... or ... experience/feel emotional & physical pain?

Comment: the very word 'feel' is only associated with sentient beings. insentient stone and water and air do not 'feel'. so, yes, it is the soul (sentient, conscious being) which experiences anything.

Comment: I don’t think that the soul can experience pleasure or pain...

Comment: @HayagreevRam, if one is pinched hard, who screams ?

Comment: @ram But if someone cuts our head with a sword, our body dies, not the soul. If someone puts fire on us, our body burns, not the soul. When we take a bath, our body gets wet, not our soul. This is mentioned in the Gita

Comment: @Hayagreev Then who feels burns of fire if not the soul? Somebody must feel it.

Comment: Until it's "individual", **yes**, it does feel pleasure and pain. Because it's able to differentiate with respect to the other "individuals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the jiva feels the pleasure and pain as long as he does not identify with the Atman.

> Upon the same tree there are two birds, one on the top, the other
>   below. The one on the top is calm, silent, and majestic, immersed in
>   his own glory; **the one on the lower branches, eating sweet and bitter
>   fruits by turns, hopping from branch to branch, is becoming happy and
>   miserable by turns.** After a time the lower bird eats an exceptionally
>   bitter fruit and gets disgustful and looks up and sees the other bird,
>   that wondrous one of golden plumage, who eats neither sweet nor bitter
>   fruit, who is neither happy nor miserable, but calm, Self-centred, and
>   sees nothing beyond his Self. The lower bird longs for this condition
>   but soon forgets it, and again begins to eat the fruits. In a little
>   while, he eats another exceptionally bitter fruit, which makes him
>   feel miserable, and he again looks up, and tries to get nearer to the
>   upper bird. Once more he forgets and after a time he looks up, and so
>   on he goes again and again, until he comes very near to the beautiful
>   bird and sees the reflection of light from his plumage playing around
>   his own body, and he feels a change and seems to melt away; still
>   nearer he comes, and everything about him melts away, and at last he
>   understands this wonderful change. The lower bird was, as it were,
>   only the substantial-looking shadow, the reflection of the higher; he
>   himself was in essence the upper bird all the time. This eating of
>   fruits, sweet and bitter, this lower, little bird, weeping and happy
>   by turns, was a vain chimera, a dream: all along, the real bird was
>   there above, calm and silent, glorious and majestic, beyond grief,
>   beyond sorrow. The upper bird is God, the Lord of this universe; and
>   the lower bird is the human soul, eating the sweet and bitter fruits
>   of this world. Now and then comes a heavy blow to the soul. For a
>   time, he stops the eating and goes towards the unknown God, and a
>   flood of light comes. He thinks that this world is a vain show. Yet
>   again the senses drag hint down, and he begins as before to eat the
>   sweet and bitter fruits of the world. Again an exceptionally hard blow
>   comes. His heart becomes open again to divine light; thus gradually he
>   approaches God, and as he gets nearer and nearer, he finds his old
>   self melting away. When he has come near enough, he sees that he is no
>   other than God, and he exclaims, "He whom I have described to you as
>   the Life of this universe, as present in the atom, and in suns and
>   moons — He is the basis of our own life, the Soul of our soul. Nay,
>   thou art That." This is what this Jnana-Yoga teaches. It tells man
>   that he is essentially divine. It shows to mankind the real unity of
>   being, and that each one of us is the Lord God Himself, manifested on
>   earth. All of us, from the lowest worm that crawls under our feet to
>   the highest beings to whom we look up with wonder and awe — all are
>   manifestations of the same Lord.
>
> Lastly, it is imperative that all these various Yogas should be
>   carried out in, practice; mere theories about them will not do any
>   good. First we have to hear about them, then we have to think about
>   them. We have to reason the thoughts out, impress them on our minds,
>   and we have to meditate on them, realise them, until at last they
>   become our whole life. No longer will religion remain a bundle of
>   ideas or theories, nor an intellectual assent; it will enter into our
>   very self. By means of intellectual assent we may today subscribe to
>   many foolish things, and change our minds altogether tomorrow. But
>   true religion never changes. Religion is realisation; not talk, nor
>   doctrine, nor theories, however beautiful they may be. It is being and
>   becoming, not hearing or acknowledging; it is the whole soul becoming
>   changed into what it believes. That is religion.

The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda, Volume 2, Practical Vedanta and Other Lectures, The Ideal of a Universal Religion

Comment: ... Upon reading carefully Swami's above example, where the lower bird is taken as the shadow aka reflection aka the human soul ... and at the same time Vivekananda says that this lower bird or human soul eats various types of fruits (feels joy and pain) .......  But isn't it the subtle body (manas, ahamkara, chitta) and the gross body, which are parts of prakriti, that does all activities & at the same time experiences joy and pain ... I mean how can the individual soul (which is beyond pain, pleasure, injury, activities) actually eat fruits of joy&pain?

Comment: The expression human soul means the embodied Atman or Jiva. It does not mean the Atman. The Atman is a mere witness. However, the jiva or the embodied Atman identifies with the subtle and physical body and the ego and hence its ego 'eats' the bitter and sweet fruits.

Comment: Hmmm, so the embodied human soul is the experiencer or bhokta. Fine.  But what about the Atman. Is it non embodied (dwells outside the body and witnesses everything?) ... coz if this Atman, is inside the body then it becomes jivatman and also becomes the experiencer and cant possibly observe once it becomes jivatman. In order to observe/witness, without being affected by joy or pain of prakriti, it must stay outside the body right?

Comment: The same soul in a gross body can't possibly remain both under Maya (as embodied jivatman / bhokta) & at the same time, being embodied, remain outside the influence of Maya as paramatman (as the witness/observer) ......  The explanation you gave above seems kinda like the philosophy of vishishtadvaita, which states, within the depth of the individual soul aka jivatman, resides another supreme soul, who even being embodied stays outside the influence of prakriti and simply witnesses.

Comment: If you reread my last comment you will see that the Jiva is the embodied Atman. The Atman even though called Jivatman when in a Jiva is NEVER an experiencer. It remains an witness even though inside the body-mind complex. So who suffers? It is the ego which suffers.

Comment: You said first that the embodied Atman/Brahman (jivatman) suffers when it identifies itself thru the subtle and gross body. And then later, you said it never suffers even after being trapped in body and always remains an observer.  Your advaitic statements are contradicting in nature ...  My point is, the one who never suffers, would not even identify itself with ego, mind and flesh body in the first place ... If you think I'm wrong feel free to correct me and help me understand advaita. Krishna said its the inner being or soul that is the bhokta and not the ego.

Comment: The embodied Atman, the jiva, does not identify with the Atman and hence suffers. I also said that Atman (by itself) never suffers even though it is embedded in a body-mind complex. These two statements are not contradictory. The embodied Atman, the jiva, is ignorant of its true nature, the Atman, and identifies with the physical and subtle body. Hence the jiva suffers through faulty identification. Your point is that one who never suffers will never identify with ego etc. What we see is in fact that such faulty identification takes place and so it cannot be debated. It is simply a fact.

Comment: There are 2 facts here. The first fact is that most Jivas do not identify with the Atman but instead think of themselves as human with bodies and minds. The second fact to yogis is that they observe the Atman in them. Advaita Vedanta is trying to reconcile these two observations. So there is no point in speculating that one who never suffers would not identify with ego etc. Yes, the whole issue is puzzling. The possible answer is that avidya maya covers up the Atman in a Jiva so succesfully that the jiva identifies with the ego, physical body and mind.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

Yes in Vyavhara (practice) and No in Paramartha (absolute). It's well explained by following verse of Rigveda (1.164.20):

> द्वा सुपर्णा सयुजा सखाया समानं वृक्षं परिषस्वजाते ।
>   तयोरन्यः पिप्पलं स्वाद्वत्त्यनश्नन्नन्यो अभिचाकशीति ॥
>
> Two birds of beautiful plumage, who are inseparable friends, reside on the self-same tree. Of these, **one eats the fruits of the tree with relish while the other looks on without eating**.

I've explained the meaning quoting commentary of Adi Shankaracharya [**here**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18121/277). Atman due to the ignorance (which can be called Jivatma) constitutes the subtle body and experience the joy and grief through subtle body. Whereas Atman (supreme self or true self or can be called Paramatman) who is omniscient and is only sees these as witness.

In other words, According to Advaita, in the influence of Maya or at Vyavharika level, Brahman can be seen as 1.Jiva and 2.Ishwara out of them Jiva experience fruits of Karma (Bhokta) and Ishwara is seer (Upadrashta and Bharta). So, the properties of Atman described in the verse of Bhagavad Gita you mentioned in question are combination of properties of Jiva and Ishwara. In absolute individual self is not different with supreme self. So, due to ignorance or upon the influence of maya Atman can be said Bhokta.

I recommend to go through [commentary of Adi Shankaracharya on that verse](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=13&field_nsutra_value=23&setgb=1) of Bhagavad Gita.

Comment: Beside , the ref. of Svetasvatara Upanishad 5.7-8 can also be given. -https://www.esamskriti.com/e/Spirituality/Upanishads-Commentary/Svetasvatara-Upanishad-~-Chap-5-The-One-Immanent-God-2.aspx

Comment: Do vesas talk of these levels ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi No, see [Which scriptures defines the three levels of reality?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13626/277).

Comment: @Pandya by that way all.commentaries can be called scriptures and all of them give contradictory meanings. These are.only opinions of sankara and not the actual.upanishad itself

Comment: @RakeshJoshi obviously commentaries on Upanishads are not the part of Upanishads.

Comment: @Pandya so these so called scriptures or commentaries which one is true..

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I didn't get it. Let's discuss in [general chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism).

Answer (score 3):

Probably here the answer will vary depending on which philosophical school one is answering from.

My answer is from ShAkta Tantra which is purely Advaitic in nature (Not to be confused with a man made philosophy though).

According to Tantras, **that the Jiva enjoys is a myth**. It's actually the Kundalini Devi who enjoys and suffers.

> Lord Shiva says:
>
> MuladhAre tu yA shaktirbhujagAkArarupini |
>  JivAtmA parameshAni
>   tanmadhe vartate sadA ||
>  BhojanecchA bhavet tasmAtnirlipto
>   jivasamgyakah |
>  Saiva sakshAd gunamayi nirguna jiva uchyate ||
>   **Jivasya bhojanam devi bhrAntireva na samshayah** |
>  GunayuktA
>   kundalini chandrasuryAgnirupini || 6
>
> O Parameswari ! In the region of MulAdhAra the snake-like Kundalini Shakti resides and
>   within it the Jiva resides always. It is the Kundalini Shakti
>   from which the desire generates; the Jiva is completely indifferent
>   regarding this. And that Kundalini is of the form of three Gunas the
>   Jiva is Nirguna (devoid of qualities). The jiva (embodied human) is
>   devoid of qualities. **Devi, for the jiva, pleasure is delusion. There
>   is no doubt about this.** Kundalini, the form of Sun, Moon and Fire, is
>   endowed with qualities.
>
> **MAtrikA Bheda Tantram Patala 3, Slokas 4,5,6.**

(NOTE - For verse 6 the translation is borrowed from [here](http://www.shivashakti.com/deviras2.htm)).

So, the enjoyment and suffering, the Jiva is unaffected by both **in truth.**

In the Tantras, there are three types of aspirants:

1. The Pashu - The Tamasik and the dualistic one. They are deluded into thinking that they themselves (i.e the Jiva) are suffering and enjoying but in truth level it is not so.

2,3- Vira (the heroic) and the Divya (divine) aspirants however both have the understanding that it's not they themselves who are enjoying/suffering.

So, while eating, for example, they imagine the Devi extended from the MulAdhAra to the tip of the tongue and consume their food by chanting a Mantra **" ... Juhoyomi kundalimukhe ... "** (I'm offering the oblation to the mouth of Kundalini Devi).

The result of the Pashu like behavior is repeated births in lower/higher worlds but that of the Vira and Divya like behaviors are liberation from bondage forever.

So, according to the Tantras **it is only a delusion (or myth) that the Jiva or soul enjoys or suffers**. It's actually not so in absolute level of reality.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not at all familiar with tantra. So by jiva you mean the individual soul jiva-atman right?  You said above its the embodied human ... I think you meant to say embodied soul. Right?

Comment: That's how the translator translated. I gave a link from where i took the translation of verse 6. Yes i meant the Jivatman only @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: Thanks. Could you please enlighten me, a bit more about this kundalini shakti, like is it prana shakti (the vital life force) ? ... Also if the jivatman doesn't suffer according to shakta tantra, then who suffers when the desires are generated by this kundalini shakti? Does the subtle and gross body suffers?

Comment: The Divine Mother (Parashakti) after creation takes rest in each Jiva at a place near the Muladhara Chakra, So Kundalini Shakti is no other than Divine Mother. For sake of creation Shiva and Shakti has to separate from each other. While Shakti stays at the base Shiva stays at the top (Sahsrara Chakra). If some one can raise this sleeping Shakti upwards and unite it with Shiva then that's Moksha. Creation exists as long as Shiva and Shakti are separate, creation dissolves when they are one again. As said in my answer the Jiva is Nirguna so it can't enjoy/suffer. It's Kundalini which/who enjoys.

Comment: @TheCrimsonUniverse It's Divine Mother's free will to create and destroy so it's she only who enjoys and suffers. The Jiva who's basically the Brahman (Sadashiva) in bondage can not do anything but just witness Mother's Lila (sport).

Comment: Thanks :) In vedanta though, brahman and prakriti unites, to create, but here in ur school it separates to start creation. They do differ somewhat but they do agree on one thing, that its prakriti that suffers.

Answer (score 3):

Jiva suffers as long as it remains deluded by Maya. Strive for realization and suffering will come to an end.

Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna / Volume 1 / [The Master's Birthday Celebration at Dakshineswar](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_1/08_masters_birthday.htm)

> God alone exists, and all else is unreal. The Divine Mother has kept all deluded by Her maya. Look at men. Most of them are entangled in worldliness. **They suffer so much, but still they have the same attachment to 'woman and gold'. The camel eats thorny shrubs, and blood gushes from its mouth; still it will eat thorns.** While suffering pain at the time of delivery, a woman says, 'Ah' I shall never go to my husband again.' But afterwards she forgets. The truth is that no one seeks God. There are people who eat the prickly leaves of the pineapple and not the fruit.